# TypeError: this.outerHTML is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get outer HTML of all text nodes of page. This is my code:

```js
var $textNodes = $("body, body *").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
});

// for testing
$textNodes.each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  text a<br/> text b
  <div>
    text c
    <strong>text d</strong> text e
  </div>
  text f<br/> text g
</div>
```

But I'm getting this error instead:

> TypeError: this.outerHTML is not a function

Think the error is related to this code:

```
console.log(this.outerHTML());
```

It would be great if someone can help...

Comment: `console.log(this.outerHTML)` Read the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML

Comment: You're trying to use it as a function with the `()` after the name; it is not a function, as the error states. *edit* also you can't get the `outerHTML` of a text node; it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to use a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript), not a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions): `this.outerHTML`.
2. You can't get [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) from these node because it's a [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/property/JavaScript) of the [**`Element`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) class, not [**`Text`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text): [**`Element.outerHTML`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML).

[image: Element]

[image: Text]

```js
var $textNodes = $("body, body *").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
});

$textNodes.each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  text a<br/> text b
  <div>
    text c
    <strong>text d</strong> text e
  </div>
  text f<br/> text g
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so so much for the explanation but unfortunately I'm getting undefined in colsole :(

Comment: @JayaBalasooriya I explained why you're getting `undefined` in a console — you have `Text` nodes that don't have the `outerHTML` property.

Comment: Thanks so much but is there a way to get outer html of text node?

Comment: @JayaBalasooriya seems like no. What do you want to achieve? Why you need an outer HTML of text nodes?

Comment: can I console log texts one by one at least?

Comment: @JayaBalasooriya yes, you can do something like `console.log(this.nodeValue);`.

Comment: unfortunately I can't vote yet but I'll promise I'll do it as soon as possible